# matlab variable shared to another function

Tags: matlab

Inside of one parent function, I have a callback function related to a button on a gui.

When the button is pressed, one of the things it does is define a variable (let's say X) that needs to be persistent so that later on, another sub function to the parent function can use X.
(i.e. callback functionA creates variable X.
later on, functionB requires variable X to be known, to know a specific path to take)

Is there any way to go about this?
I've read up on using handles to pass it to the second function, but I can't seem to figure out a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Indirectly from Matlab [`guidata` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html):

in the first callback function:

```
function first_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

% add some additional data as a new field called x
handles.x = 1;
% Save the change you made to the structure
guidata(hObject, handles)
```

in the second callback function simply use `handles.x` because handles is already passed as a parameter to the second callback, if they belong to the same parent figure.

```
function second_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

% a will have the value 1
a = handles.x;
```

Note: Even though you are saving handles to `hObject` (which is the current object that has called the callback function), the handles structures is visible to other objects on the same figure. Saving `handles` structure to `hObject` and saving to the parent figure are virtually the same. Also you only need to use `guidata` if you make changes to the `handles` structure. If you only read the value of a `handles` member, you don't need to save it after that.

Comment: Sorry, just to make sure of something, and to clarify a little...
I actually have three pushButton uicontrols, all of which return the value (well two actually, let's say, x and y). When replaced in the function, the second (y) set as handles.y return the "error" 

"Variable 'handles', apparently a structure, is changed but the value seems unused". Any ideas?

Comment: Remember that `handles` is a structure. You cannot refer to an undefined structure member. i.e. you first have to define `handles.x = 1` before you can say `a = handles.x`. If there are situations where your second button may want to read the value of `handles.x` before it's set, define `handles.x = 0` or similar default values in the figure load callback and save it using `guidata`

Comment: By figure load callback I mean `_OpeningFcn` callback function of your main figure.

Comment: I am having issues getting this to work, sorry, a little new to a lot of the concepts brought forward in matlab.
When I try to define a based off handles.x, it is tell me that there is not enough input arguments.

Comment: Can I get some more help here? In a small test file I attempted to work the handles, but I keep recieving the input argument error

Comment: "There is not enough input argument" usually means you are trying to call a function with fewer number of arguments that are allowed. You need to check the line of code the error message refers to to see what function is being called and what parameters are missing. This is a separate question that the one you posted here.